# From a deep learning point of view, is there a lower limit on the number of hours of speech needed to train a neural net

Tags: neural-networks, compression, machine-translation

From a deep learning practitioner's point of view, is there a lower limit on the number of hours of speech needed to train a neural net to translate speech to text? [An estimate from CMU](https://www.quora.com/How-many-voice-data-is-needed-for-the-training-of-commercial-DNN-HMM-ASR-system-with-accuracy-of-90) is 3000-5000 hours for 90% accuracy 
commercial quality speech recognition. Is there is a minimum amount of information needed to reproduce the complexity of the actual language.  I.e., if you had 5000 hours and compress it down with a neural net, there is some minimum size neural net needed to do a good job at speech recognition.   You can call that the "bit complexity of a natural language".  Does inverting the compression ratio tell you how many hours of speech, at a minimum, you would need to train a commercial quality speech recognition system?  For context, the classic paper [Prediction and Entropy of Printed English](https://www.princeton.edu/~wbialek/rome/refs/shannon_51.pdf) seems relevant.